# How to verify a story is posted to a user's Facebook timeline without using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using `FB.ui` method in Facebook JavaScript SDK to trigger feed dialog which allows user to post a story to their timeline. I want to keep track of number of stories a user posted on their Facebook timeline by calling a REST API and pass in the post ID in FB.ui's callback function.

My question is can I verify whether the story did posted in the user's timeline? I need to do the verification at server side based on the post ID. And I can't use Graph API to retrieve the post because I don't have an access token.

Here is the script:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: $target.data('link'),
    picture: $target.data('picture'),
    name: $target.data('name'),
    caption: $target.data('caption'),
    description: $target.data('description')
};      
function callback(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        // Call REST API to update share count
    }
}
FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Comment: If you don’t have an access token with `read_stream` permission, you can only check the post id if the user chose to make the post public. But why do you have to check this anyway? Sounds like you want to reward users for posting stuff – which is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policies.

Comment: @CBroe, how do I check if the user make the post public? I would like to add gamification element to my application and award user a virtual badge if they share something on their Facebook timeline. I'm not sure if that is considered direct reward?